# Jquery loading the link instead of returning false

Tags: jquery, json

Here is the jquery code:

```
   $('.edit-function').click( function() {
       $.getJSON( $(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
               $('input[name=add-name]').val(data.name);
             });
       return false;
       });
   });
```

The problem is every time I run this instead of it updating the value of the form on the current page it goes to the url from the attr. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra `});` in your posted code, it should just be:

```
$('.edit-function').click( function() {
   $.getJSON( $(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      $('input[name=add-name]').val(data.name);
   });
   return false;
});
```

Also, make sure you're attaching the `click` handler once the element is in the page (and [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is a better option when you want to *just* prevent navigation), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.edit-function').click(function(e) {
    $.getJSON($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
      $('input[name=add-name]').val(data.name);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yes I already do $(function() {, I was just showing the snippet of code that I was having issues with. However I will look into preventdefault, especially if that is a better option.

Comment: Perhaps that's the }); of his document.ready that he didn't copy? @John, make sure to wrap your code in a $(document).ready(function() { code here }); -- edit, you are already as stated above.

Comment: @Flavio: Yeah it was an extra }); Just didnt see it for some reason, however this code is wrapped around the .ready, this is just the snippet of code I was having issues with. Thank you all for the feedback!